# What role did Bergson have in modernist art?

Tags: modernism, bergson

What role did Bergson have in modernist art? All I know, and I may be misremembering anyway, is that he was borrowed by the Italian Futurists, especially in their manifestos, presumably for his analysis of time and movement (and not his sense of humour).

Comment: See https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/interpreting-bergson/bergsons-philosophy-of-art/AEEFEABE06838B233D72A220282ADBA6

Comment: [Henri Bergson and British Modernism](https://www.google.it/books/edition/Henri_Bergson_and_British_Modernism/_u8goQyhQm8C) and [Understanding Bergson, Understanding Modernism](https://www.google.it/books/edition/Understanding_Bergson_Understanding_Mode/Bo_FAgAAQBAJ).

Comment: Yes, time and movement (Futurism and Vorticism) but also memory (Proust, Joyce).